# SQLAlchemy, adding a column of ARRAY type throw me "can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.ARRAY'>"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add a simple string / integer array type column in my sqlAlchemy Base class, but with no luck. Each time it give me an exception that it can't render the array type. I don't understand why. I am missing something?

Here is my class:

```
class Item_detail(Base):
    __tablename__  = 'item_detail'
    id             = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    detail_label   = Column(String)
    images_link    = Column(ARRAY(String()), default=[])

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///bifi.db')

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

But then, sqlalchemy throw me that:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 79, in _compiler_dispatch
    raise exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(visitor, cls)
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'item_detail', column 'images_link'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteTypeCompiler object at 0x10f9aa210> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.ARRAY'>
```

I don't understand why I can't render it. I tried with different array type with no luck.

Comment: You're connecting to a SQLite backend, which does not support `ARRAY` from PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

SQLAlchemy's ARRAY can be used in PostageSQL back-end currently (SQLAlchemy 1.3.18). The description for ARRAY that is written on "sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py" says:

> This type serves as the basis for all ARRAY operations.
> However, currently **only the PostgreSQL backend has support
> for SQL arrays in SQLAlchemy**.

So, if you want to use SQLAlchemy's ARRAY, you should install PostageSQL and psycopg2. Then create engine as following.

```
DATABASE = 'postgresql'
USER = 'postgres'
PASSWORD = 'your password'
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = '5432'
DB_NAME = 'postgres'
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}:{PORT}/{DB_NAME }')
```